# Is there a way to dynamically change maximumSelectionLength on kartik/select2 in yii2?

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I am trying to update through javascript the maximumSelectionLength parameter of a select2 field (**listeProduits**) based on the value of a second select2 (**nom_id**) when it is changed.
I'm first storing the maxChildren values in a js table before loading the form so that I can access it on the client side when a new nom_id is selected.
The below approach doesn't work though as it messes up the listeProduits select2.

```
<script>
var nomMaxChildren = <?= json_encode(ArrayHelper::map(Nom::find()->asArray()->where(['type' => 'Boite'])->all(), 'id', 'max_children')); ?>;
alert(nomMaxChildren[1]);
</script>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'nom_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Nom::find()->asArray()->where(['type' => 'Boite'])->all(), 'id', 'nom'),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app','Select a name...')],
    'pluginEvents' => [
       "select2:select" => "function() { 
            $('select[name =\"listeProduits[]\"]').select2({
                maximumSelectionLength: nomMaxChildren[\$(this).val()]
            });
       }",
    ]
]);?>

<label class="control-label"><?= Yii::t('app', 'Produits')?></label>';

<?= Select2::widget([
    'attribute' => 'listeProduits',
    'name' => 'listeProduits',
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Produit::find()->asArray()->where(['statut_id' => 2])->andWhere(['boite_id' => null])->orWhere(['boite_id' => $model->id])->all(), 'id', 'numero_de_serie'),
    'value' => (is_null($model->id)) ? null : ArrayHelper::map(Produit::find()->asArray()->where(['boite_id' => $model->id])->all(), 'id', 'id'),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => Yii::t('app','Select products')],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'maximumSelectionLength' => (isset($model->nom)) ? $model->nom->max_children : null,
    ],
    'showToggleAll' => false,
]);?>
```

Also if you have any idea on how to validate the fact that the maximumSelectionLength is ok on client side, it would be great :D

Answer (score -1):

set `maximumSelectionLength` property dynamically :

```
$('#demo-select').select2({ maximumSelectionLength: 1 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's what I do here :
           "select2:select" => "function() { 
            $('select[name =\"listeProduits[]\"]').select2({
                maximumSelectionLength: nomMaxChildren[\$(this).val()]
            });
       }",
But that makes the select2 very narrow